# How to return back to current page after languare has changed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET MVC4 application allows to select language:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="selected_language">
                <a href="/admin/Home/SetCulture?culture=et" title="et">
                    et
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/Home/SetCulture?culture=en" title="en">
                    en
                </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

After link in clicked, controller is called to change language:

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
{
    // Validate input
    culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
    // Save culture in a cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
    if (cookie != null)
        cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
    else
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
        cookie.Value = culture;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

After language is changed, home page is shown.
How to force current page where link is clicked display instead ?
RedirectToAction("Index") should changed to return to current page.

html is in Site.Master and can called from many different pages. 
MVC template account controller LogOn method implements this: it receives returnurl parameter. How to pass this parameter to controller ?

Bootstrap 3, jquery, ASP.NET MVC4 are used.

Comment: you may pass addition parameter like public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string ActionName)  return RedirectToAction(ActionName);

Comment: hmtl code in is Site.Master. How to find ActionName parameter value in site master. There may be also query string in pages. How to pass query string also ?

Comment: Store Action name in a hidden field in site master, using jquery/javascript pass hidden field value to query string.

Comment: adamshakhabov answer recommends to use ajax and `location.reload()`. Which is better, your solution or adamas one ? Or maybe there is way to do it without javascript, how get whole url in controller like first answer recommends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX:

**View**

```
<a href=# onclick="return Et();">et</a>

<script type="text/jscript">
    function Et()
    {
        //maybe do something
        $.get("/Home/Et?culture=et");                
    };
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public EmptyResult Et(string culture)
 {  
   //do something
   return new EmptyResult();
 }
```

Comment: This does not refresh the page. How to refresh page also ?

Comment: Return a jsonresult, check those result, if succeed refresh page using javascript window.location.reload()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
{
    // Validate input
    culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
    // Save culture in a cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
    if (cookie != null)
        cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
    else
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
        cookie.Value = culture;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    return Redirect(Request.Referrer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I tried but got compile error `Error 3 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'Referrer' and no extension method 'Referrer' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` How to fix ?

Comment: use: HttpContext.Current.HttpRequest.Referrer.ToString()

Comment: I tried code in answer and in comment but got the same compile error. How to fix ?